# Visual studio do not see function declaration in some cases

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

For example:

```
void main(){
foo1();

} 

fooTarget();
foo1(foo2(););
foo2(foo3(););
foo3(foo4(););
foo4(foo5(););
foo5(
foo6();
fooTarget(); //Identifier not found
);
foo6(
fooTarget(); //It Works!
);
```

what is it?
if I paste code from fooTarget() to foo5() it works too

A reduced testcase from actual code:

```
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char word[] = "hey";
    int wordSize = getWordLenght(word); // error: getWordLenght not declared
}

int getWordLenght(char *word){
    return strlen(word);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `foo5(foo6(); fooTarget(););` compiles at all. I'm not at all sure what it would mean. When I try to compile your code above, I get *lots* of errors. Rearranging it so the declarations precede use in `main` eliminates some, but still leaves lots about `syntax error, missing ")" before ";"`.

Comment: I'm surprised too, I can provide code where I have this trouble

Comment: I think some real code that displays (only) the error that concerns you would be hugely helpful. What you've posted above has so many errors it's hard to guess which you care about.

Comment: there is no prototypes also, this is only structure

Comment: Right now, all you've shown us is a mess. Though vaguely similar, it's not C++ (or even C) and guessing your problems from what you've posted is essentially impossible.

Comment: http://mishkapp-projects.googlecode.com/files/ResearchComponent9.cpp

Comment: don't look at non syntax errors. In process(char*); in does not work but in reverseWord(char*) it works

Comment: You're trying to use `getWordLenght` (which you've misspelled, BTW) before you define/declare it. Cut and paste it so it precedes `process()` and the code compiles fine.

Comment: C++ supports both early and late binding, but this has nothing to do with either one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you posted in the comments you're using a function that hasn't been declared yet. It's declared later, but C++ doesn't look at later declarations to resolve functions.

<sub>Also, the 'th' digraph is spelled 'th', not 'ht'</sub>

Comment: To add to that you can use a function prototype as a declaration if you want to put the implementation after the location where you make your calls if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
foo5(
foo6();
fooTarget(); //Identifier not found
);
```

If you remove newlines, this will be parsed as:

```
foo5( foo6(); fooTarget(); );
```

Which is, of course, not correct C++ code.

You have plenty of other errors in your posted code.  For example, you don't specify return types for any of your function prototypes -- assuming they are intended to be prototypes.